# USB wifi Card AWUS036NHR-RTL8192cu : Card not blinks like normal

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek

I am using Ubuntu 13.10. I have a AWUS036NHR-RTL8192cu USB wifi Card.

I have installed USB wifi card Driver by following all the instructions available in web. But still getting error.

It detect the networks but *Cannot Connect*. The light on the wifi card adaptor is continuously blinking.

But this blinking is not like in other wifi USB Adaptors.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, ensure you have the necessary prerequisites:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms git
```

Clone the updated driver with `git`:

```
git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
```

Set it up as a DKMS module:

```
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
```

Build and install the driver:

```
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.8
```

Refresh the module list:

```
sudo depmod -a
```

Ensure the native (and broken) kernel driver is blacklisted:

```
sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
```

Let's not take any chances. Instruct Ubuntu to load the new driver when it starts up.

```
echo 8192cu | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Reboot.

### You're done.

<sub>Thanks to [P. Varet](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes) for this awesome fix.</sub>

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.

Comment: I recommend reading the README file before installing the driver as it contains up-to-date instructions.